# Using jQuery to find a substring

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, substring

Say you have a string: "The ABC cow jumped over XYZ the moon" and you want to use jQuery to get the substring between the "ABC" and "XYZ", how would you do this? The substring should be "cow jumped over". Many thanks!

Comment: First of all, you don't use jQuery to do string manipulation - that's Javascript/ECMAScript. Secondly, can you be more specific about the logic used to grab that string? Is there a pattern?

Comment: Question for jQuery not tagged with jQuery

Comment: Well anyways why need jQuery? cannot simple javascript work for you

Comment: In my eyes, this question shouldn't be tagged with jQuery for the very reason that it has nothing to do with jQuery. ;)

Answer (score 6):

This has nothing to do with jQuery, which is primarily for DOM traversal and manipulation.  You want a simple regular expression:

```
var str = "The ABC cow jumped over XYZ the moon";
var sub = str.replace(/^.*ABC(.*)XYZ.*$/m, '$1');
```

The idea is you're using a [String.replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/String/Replace) with a regular expression which matches your opening and closing delimiters, and replacing the whole string with the part matched between the delimiters.

The first argument is a regular expression.  The trailing `m` causes it to match over multiple lines, meaning your text between `ABC` and `XYZ` may contain newlines. The rest breaks down as follows:

- `^` start at the beginning of the string
- `.*` a series of 0 or more characters
- `ABC` your opening delimiter
- `(.*)` match a series of 0 or more characters
- `XYZ` your closing delimiter
- `.*` a series of 0 or more characters
- `$` match to the end of the string

The second parameter, the replacement string, is '$1'.  `replace` will substitute in parenthesized submatchs from your regular exprsesion - the `(.*)` portion from above.  Thus the return value is the entire string replace with the parts between the delimiters.

Comment: I thought jQuery has functions: substring and indexof, and that these might be able to be used together to get the substring.

Comment: Could you briefly explain how this works: str.replace(/^.*ABC(.*)XYZ.*$/, '$1');

Comment: @Steve - It's JavaScript that has functions like substring and indexof. jQuery deals mainly with the DOM of a page.

Comment: Thanks very much to all for the help!!

Comment: Meagar, your explanation is great, and clearly explains who it works. Just a few minor questions:

1. Are the () parenthesis required ONLY as a way to indicate a submatch in the second parameter of the repace function or would this have also itenfified the submatches: /^.*ABC.*XYZ.*$/ but not worked for what we are trying to do in this case?

2. Does this regular expression have 7 submatches:
^
.*
ABC
.*
XYZ
.*
$

3. Does the $1 mean to use the first parenthesized submatch ? At first it thought it might mean to use the second submatch in the serries (the first being $0).

Steve

Comment: @Steve The sub-match substitution starts at `$1`, not `$0`, and the sub-matches in question must have parentheses around them to denote them as such.  `/^.*ABC.*XYZ.*$/` would still match the entire string, but it's the `(.*)` that makes it useful by allowing us to extract the characters matched via the `$1` replace parameter.

Answer (score 3):

You may not need to use jQuery on this one.  I'd do something like this:

```
function between(str, left, right) {
    if( !str || !left || !right ) return null;
    var left_loc = str.indexOf(left);
    var right_loc = str.indexOf(right);
    if( left_loc == -1 || right_loc == -1 ) return null;
    return str.substring(left_loc + left.length, right_loc);
}
```

No guarantees the above code is bug-free, but the idea is to use the standard [substring()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp) function.  In my experience these types of functions work the same across all browsers.

Comment: i like this one because i hate regex, wonder if that is good reason :)

Answer (score 1):

Meagar, your explanation is great, and clearly explains who it works.

Just a few minor questions:

- Are the () parenthesis required ONLY as a way to indicate a submatch in the second parameter of the relpace function or would this also identify the submatches: /^.*ABC.*XYZ.*$/ but not work for what we are trying to do in this case?
- Does this regular expression have 7 submatches:

^
.*
ABC
.*
XYZ
.*
$

- Does the $1 mean to use the first parenthesized submatch? At first I thought it might mean to use the second submatch in the series (the first being $0).

Thanks,

Steve

Answer (score 0):

Just to show you how you would use jQuery and meagar's regex. Let's say that you've got an HTML page with the following `P` tag:

```
<p id="grabthis">The ABC cow jumped over XYZ the moon</p>
```

To grab the string, you would use the following jQuery/JavaScript mix (sounds kind of stupid, since jQuery is JavaScript, but see jQuery as a JavaScript DOM library):

```
$(document).ready(function() { // Wait until the document has been fully loaded
  var pStr=$("#grabthis").text(); // Grab the text from the P tag and put it into a JS variable
  var subStr=pStr.replace(/^.*ABC(.*)XYZ.*$/m, '$1'); // Run the regex to grab the middle string

  alert(subStr); // Output the grabbed middle string
});
```

Or the shorter version:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  alert($("#grabthis").text().replace(/^.*ABC(.*)XYZ.*$/m, '$1'));
});
```

The replace function is a JavaScript function. I hope this clears the confusion.