# jQuery - get values inside parentheses

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I got a HTML Table with values inside each row.
The datas inside the  consist the following format:

ABCD (1000.50)

```
$('.tdclass').each(function(index){
  var test = push($(this).text().match(?regex?));
});
```

Well, regex is definitely not one of my strength ;-)
What is the according regex to get the values inside the parentheses?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You might want to use indexOf() and substring() like this:

var test = push($(this).text();
test = test.substring(test.indexOf('('),test.length-1);

should work if you always have that named pattern.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If the first part of a string is a fixed length, you can avoid complicated procedures entirely using [`slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice):

```
var str = "ABCD (1000.50)";

alert(str.slice(6, -1));
//-> "1000.50"
```

Otherwise, you can use [`indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) and, if you need it, [`lastIndexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf) to get the value:

```
var str = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO (1000.50)",
    pos = str.indexOf("(") + 1;

alert(str.slice(pos, -1));
//-> "1000.50"

alert(str.slice(pos, str.lastIndexOf(")");
//-> "1000.50"
```

Answer (score 1):

A minimal regex of `\((.*)\)` would do the trick, however this doesn't account for multiple brackets, and there's no need to include 4 characters prior to that. It literally says 'match (, followed by as many non-new-line characters as possible, followed by )'

Comment: var str = "ABCD (1000.50)";
var test = str.match('\((.*)\)');

This gives me the result of
ABCD (1000.50),ABCD (1000.50),ABCD (1000.50)

Is there something wrong inside match()?

Comment: You need to use /regex/ rather than 'regex', eg: str.match(/\\((.*)\\)/);

Answer (score 0):

Look here: [Using jQuery to find a substring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3027379/using-jquery-to-find-a-substring)

But **substring(), indexof()**  might be easier than regex.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp

Comment: What's the downvote for? At least leave a comment to explain it. The OP wrote " regex is definitely not one of my strength" and asked for "any help".